# How to get name of objects in global namespace in javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object, global

I am experiencing a javascript bug in internet explorer and I suspect its due to a name of a div matching with a global object.

My application loads many javascript libraries.

I want to find what global objects are loaded at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since all user JS defined global objects/vars are properties of the window object, you can list all the enumerable ones with this:

```
for (var item in window) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

This will get you a list of a lot of things including all global functions.  If you want to filter out global functions, you can use this:

```
for (var item in window) {
    var type = typeof window[item];
    if (type != "function") {
        console.log(item + " (" + type + ")");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ,I actually what I was looking for was I got under DOM Tab in firebug.

Comment: This won't necessarily give you all properties. You'll only get enumerable ones.

Comment: @amnotiam - the point here was to get a list that includes all user JS global functions and vars and any global vars that the system might have defined (like those that mimic some named objects).  Those will be in this list.  Other window properties/methods may or may not be enumerable, so they may or may not be in the list, but that isn't what we're looking for here.

Comment: I know the OP asked about querying within the browser, but what is the equivalent within Node?

Comment: @colminator - Globals in node.js are on the `global` object.  So, instead of iterating properties of the `window` object, you would iterate properties of the `global` object.  Note, it's also possible to have global properties that are configured to not be enumerable so they wouldn't show up.  And, as this is a  really old answer, one may now want to use `Object.keys(global)` to get all the property names instead of `for/in`).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inspect the `window` object in Chrome/Firefox devtools: just type `window` in the devtools console and expand the object to view its members.

[image]